# How to use strcat with a char* of an unspecified length

Tags: c, strcat

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* changeString(char *inputString);

int main() {
   printf("Changed string is %s\n", changeString("42"));
}

char* changeString(char *inputString) {
    static const char* someStrings[3] = {"abc", "def", "ghi"};
    char* output;
    strcat(output, someStrings[1]);
    return output;
}
```

I'm trying to append a `char*` to another `char*` however the `strcat` keeps resulting in a segmentation fault because the `char*` has no size, changing `char* output;` to `char output[100];` fixes the segmentation fault, but then I am returning the wrong type and I can't print the answer in `printf`.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I know the example above seems to do nothing of value, I changed it to demonstrate the logic I am using.

Comment: "*... trying to append a char**  *to another char** ...": `char*` is a pointer to character. Appending one to pointer to another does not make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not allocated memory for the output string. Do use malloc() to allocate memory and then try strcat.

Comment: +1. It's also worth noting that changing output to char array and returning pointer to the local array is not a good idea.

Comment: if it fits the purpose, it's a possible solution, it is not a "not good idea" per se. (it's just not the better option in the vast majority of real world scenarios but this is another matter)

Comment: @ShinTakezou I guess you overlooked "and returning **pointer to the local array**". That is "not a good idea" per se. (A _static_ array as in your answer might be, of course.)

Comment: @ShinTakezou No problem, that happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically allocate memory, or keep a static storage you can pass to the caller (but then your program won't be thread safe, if you care).

```
   static char output[100];
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `output` does not point to anything and has an undefined value. The error you receive is because you're trying to write to that unknown address.

First you must allocate some memory for the output string.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing info in a piece of unallocated memory. Use `malloc` to allocate some memory, then use `strncat` to make sure it isn't going out of range:

```
char* output;
output = (char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
output[0] = '\0';
strncat(output, someStrings[1], 100);
```

Then, when you are done with the `output` result, call `free()` to give the memory back to the system. Mind you, you are treading into complex matter here. Do not think of dynamic memory allocation lightly.

Consult the manpages for more information. Or this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation